# Flex and Bison, parse command line arguments

Tags: command, arguments, line, yacc, flex-lexer

I'm using Flex and Bison, and I would like my lex/parse to analyse text from command line, for example if I have : *mybin mytext* , I would like my yyparse to analyse *mytext* (which is not a file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `yy_scan_string` to set the flex input buffer to a specified string (`argv[1]` in this case). See the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html#Multiple-Input-Buffers) for details.